# Transform config to app.release.config with Setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, app-config, setup-project, config-transformation

I'm using config transform so I can have other settings when building in Release mode. (used this tool: [ConfigurationTransform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform))

Now I'm also using VS 2015 installer project ([MS VS 2015 installer projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects))

I have this problem that when I create a setup in Release mode my config file isn't being transformed to the new app.release.config. While my release output directory gives me the correct app.config.

Is there anybody that can help me with this?